# How to escape plus sign on mac os x (BSD) sed?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed, grep

I'm trying to find and replace one or more occurrences of a character using sed on a mac, sed from the BSD General Commands.

I try:

```
echo "foobar" | sed -e "s/o+//g
```

expecting to see:

```
fbar
```

But instead I see

```
foobar
```

I can of course just expand the plus manually with:

```
echo "foobar" | sed -e "s/oo*//g"
```

but what do I have to do to get the plus sign working?

Comment: using `/g` flag, `s/o//g` is enough to replace all `o` occurrences.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using the `/g` flag, `s/o//g` is enough to replace all o occurrences.

**Why `+` doesn't work as expected:** in old, obsolete re `+` is an ordinary character (as well as `|`, `?`). You should specify `-E` flag to `sed` to make it using modern regular expressions:

```
echo "foobar" | sed -E -e "s/o+//"
# fbar
```

Source: `man 7 re_format`.

Comment: +1, with the `-E` flag it works as described. For some reason I couldn’t find that in the man/info pages, though. Officially it appears that the `-r` and `--regexp-extended` options are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "foobar" | sed -e "s/o\\+//g"
```

worked for me on Mac OS X 10.6.

I remembered that I replaced my BSD version of sed with GNU sed 4.2, so this may or may not work for you.

Comment: In Terminal.app you may need to use a double backslash.

Comment: @eyelidlessness Doesn't work either. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Sed is sad for regexes. You could either try the -E, which might work with BSD, or you could try this one instead:

```
sed -e "s/o\{1,\}/"
```

Perhaps there are too many sed's out there to have a usable tool on any system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, on linux or unix.

```
echo "foobar" | perl -pe "s/o+//g"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Use this can solve the problem, and don't need care about the escape issue.