# Sed extract 2nd word

Tags: regex, sed, terminal

I was wondering why it didn't work when I do:

```
echo "d_suites/k_val/tests/asm/logs/kf_on_stage1 FAILED 0:00:22 Jul 22 22:33 " | 
    sed 's/[ \t]*\([^ \t]+\)[ \t]+\([^ \t]+\).*/\2/'
```

but this one (change + to * ) works:

```
echo "d_suites/k_val/tests/asm/logs/kf_on_stage1 FAILED 0:00:22 Jul 22 22:33 " |
     sed 's/[ \t]*\([^ \t]*\)[ \t]*\([^ \t]*\).*/\2/'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sed does not support the `+` wildcard by default.

```
$ echo "aaabbbccc" | sed "s/a+/XXX/g"
aaabbbccc
```

You can enable it with the `-r` flag ([on GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-regexps)) or `-E` flag (on [Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) and, I suspect, *BSD sed) because these options enable the use of extended regular expressions (in opposition to basic regular expressions):

```
$ echo "aaabbbccc" | sed -E "s/a+/XXX/g"
XXXbbbccc
```

If you use GNU sed, it [supports](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions) the `+` as a repeater in the basic regex mode if you escape it with a backslash:

```
$ echo "aaabbbccc" | sed "s/a\+/XXX/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one doesn't work because you need to escape your +'s, like this:

```
echo "d_suites/k_val/tests/asm/logs/kf_on_stage1 FAILED 0:00:22 Jul 22 22:33 " | 
    sed 's/[ \t]*\([^ \t]\+\)[ \t]\+\([^ \t]\+\).*/\2/'
```

**Edit**

For more info about why, read [this very informative comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453760/how-to-escape-plus-sign-on-mac-os-x-bsd-sed/4453890#4453890).

Comment: thanks man, it now works, but I have to say, treating + and * differently is hard to understand.

Comment: Adding the -E flag and removing those escapes will make your regex more readable.

Comment: I tried sed -E -e , it didn't work, but anyway, it was a informative comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not completely married to sed, awk would be more readable:

```
echo "..." | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited - now referring to `[^ \t]`

`[^ \t]+` is 1-n tabs, *requiring* there to be a non-tab.
`[^ \t]*` is 0-n tabs, *not requiring* there to be a non-tab.

You *don't* have a non-tab in your input string there

Comment: I know the difference between + and *, but \([^ \t]*\) and \([^ \t]+\) is what I can not understand.

Comment: [^ \t] means anything that is not a space or a tab.

Comment: `[^\t]` is any non-tab character. So `[^\t]+` is 1-n non-tabs, while `[^\t]*` is 0-n non-tabs. Convenient, eh?

Comment: Oops. I altered the answer to reflect your comments. It's still more or less the same answer though - the `+` requires a match

Comment: ([^ \t]*) VS ([^ \t]+), please try my command, why is ([^ \t]+) unable to extract 2nd word. I do know what [^ \t] means please ...