# Regular expression substitution

Tags: regex, linux, sed, gnu

I am trying to perform some modification on a typical g++ command line. I am trying to construct a regex looking for `-o object_filename.o` constructs. In order to test my matching pattern, I launch it in sed with an empty string as a substitution. But it does not work as expected since it removes nothing...

`$echo "-o toto.o" | sed 's/-o [^ ]+//'

-o toto.o`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `-E` flag; [without it, `+` is not treated as a regex meta-character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453890/335858):

```
$echo "-o toto.o" | sed -E 's/-o [^ ]+//'
```

The above produces an empty output, as expected.

Comment: great. I am using gnu sed on linux. "-r" seems the right option in my case.

Comment: Yes `-E` is an alias for `-r` however generally it's better to use `-E` for portability!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then `sed -E 's/-o.+?\.o//'` should do what you want:

```
$ cat file

g++ .. -o object_filename.o some more options
g++ .. -o object1.o some more options
g++ .. -o foo_bar.o some more options

$ sed -E 's/-o.+?\.o//' file

g++ ..  some more options
g++ ..  some more options
g++ ..  some more options
```