# Sed command append email address

Tags: regex, sed, osx-lion

I have a csv file and I want to append all emails with .example.com. The result will be  foo@bar.com.example.com
I want to do this ussing sed command from terminal but I can't figure out what is the correct syntax.
Example:

```
email1@foo.bar;name1;surname1
email3@foo.bar;name2;surname2
email3@foo.bar;name3;surname3
```

Should become

```
email1@foo.bar.example.com;name1;surname1
email3@foo.bar.example.com;name2;surname2
email3@foo.bar.example.com;name3;surname3
```

I tried with `sed -i "" -e 's/\(@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\)/\1.example.com/g'` file.csv but it isn't working

Comment: are all the emails the same or unique?

Comment: What is your input format?  Is each line an email address?  Is the email address in a particular column?  Does each line need to be modified?

Comment: the line is like this: email1@foo.bar;bla bla;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just noticed the [osx-lion](/questions/tagged/osx-lion) tag, which means you're using BSD sed. You'll need the `-E` flag to make the `+` work:

```
$ cat > file

email1@foo.bar;name1;surname1
email3@foo.bar;name2;surname2
email3@foo.bar;name3;surname3

$ sed -E 's/(@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)/\1.example.com/' file

email1@foo.bar.example.com;name1;surname1
email3@foo.bar.example.com;name2;surname2
email3@foo.bar.example.com;name3;surname3
```

Your character class also needs to check for `a-z` as well as `A-Z`, since they are case-sensitive by default.

Reference: [How to escape plus sign on mac os x (BSD) sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453760/how-to-escape-plus-sign-on-mac-os-x-bsd-sed)

Comment: I've manage to fix this: sed -i ".bkp" -E "s/(@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)/&.example.com/g" file

Comment: If you're using `&` in the replacement, you don't need your parentheses in the match either :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could just insert the text in front of the first semicolon:

```
sed 's/;/.example.com;/'
```

Comment: won't it change `name1;` to `name1.example.com;` which he don't want

Comment: No because I did not use the `g` flag so it will only change the first semicolon

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:
sed -i ".bkp" -E "s/(@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)/&.example.com/g" file.csv

Comment: The parenthese are redundant

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`sed -re 's/(\w+@\w+.\w+)/\11.example.com/g' temp.txt`