# Can not extract the capture group with either sed or grep

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

I want to extract the value pair from a key-value pair syntax but I can not.
Example I tried:

```
echo employee_id=1234 | sed 's/employee_id=\([0-9]+\)/\1/g'
```

But this gives `employee_id=1234` and not `1234` which is actually the capture group.

What am I doing wrong here? I also tried:

```
echo employee_id=1234| egrep -o employee_id=([0-9]+)
```

but no success.

Comment: AFAIK sed does not support the '+' quantifier. Instead you have to type the previous item twice: [0-9][0-9]* as anubhava does in his answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape plus sign on mac os x (BSD) sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453760/how-to-escape-plus-sign-on-mac-os-x-bsd-sed)

Comment: echo 'employee_id=1234' | cut -d '=' -f 2

Answer (score 108):

**1. Use `grep -Eo`:** (as `egrep` is deprecated)

```
echo 'employee_id=1234' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'

1234
```

**2. using `grep -oP` (PCRE):**

```
echo 'employee_id=1234' | grep -oP 'employee_id=\K([0-9]+)'

1234
```

**3. Using `sed`:**

```sh
echo 'employee_id=1234' | sed 's/^.*employee_id=\([0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/'

1234
```

Comment: None of your answers are relevant. The first I can not use because I need only the number after `employee_id=`, the second does not work at all and the third one picks the number and if I modify it, it gives what I need but the difference with mine is that you use `*` in the digits part while I use `+`.  
Why does this matter?

Comment: `+` is only allowed in extended regex available with `sed -r` or `sed -E`

Comment: 2 worked for me as a way to get PHP version for use in an Ansible playbook `php -v | grep -P -o "^PHP\s\K([0-9]{1}\.?[0-9]{0,2}\.?[0-9]{0,2})\s"`

Comment: What does `\K` do?

Comment: @Nae: `\K` is PCRE directive to reset all matched info.

Answer (score 34):

To expand on anubhava's answer number **2**, the general pattern to have grep return *only* the capture group is:

```
$ regex="$precedes_regex\K($capture_regex)(?=$follows_regex)"
$ echo $some_string | grep -oP "$regex"
```

so

```
# matches and returns b
$ echo "abc" | grep -oP "a\K(b)(?=c)" 
b 
# no match
$ echo "abc" | grep -oP "z\K(b)(?=c)"
# no match
$ echo "abc" | grep -oP "a\K(b)(?=d)"
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`

```
echo 'employee_id=1234' | awk -F= '{print $2}'
1234
```

Answer (score 5):

use sed -E for extended regex

```
    echo employee_id=1234 | sed -E 's/employee_id=([0-9]+)/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 4):

You are specifically asking for `sed`, but in case you may use something else - any POSIX-compliant shell can do parameter expansion which doesn't require a fork/subshell:

```
foo='employee_id=1234'
var=${foo%%=*}
value=${foo#*=}
```

```
$ echo "var=${var} value=${value}"
var=employee_id value=1234
```