# grep for a value after two words

Tags: regex, bash, grep

In a file there is are repeatedly lines like

```
value for = 0.658
value b = 0.431
value ty = 0.001
```

The line starts with `value`. I would like to only grep the number in the `value for` line (0.658) and there is always the `=` before it. The problem is that `=` is also in front of the other lines of the file. I know how to grep for the line of the two words `value` and `for` but don't know how to grep the number only?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
grep -oP 'value for = \K.*' filename
```

Output:

```
0.658
```

See: http://www.charlestonsw.com/perl-regular-expression-k-trick/

Comment: Note that this uses two non-standard (non-POSIX) options to `grep`: `-o` to print only the data that is matched, and `-P` to use PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions).  The `-o` option is found in GNU `grep` and in BSD (Mac OS X) `grep`; the `-P` option is only found in GNU `grep`, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `grep` will print the entire line if you have a match (see '[man grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)').

The -o option will instead output only the part of lines matching the [regex](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/). So, to output all numbers on lines with numbers we can do:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' filename
```

To restrict to lines with 'value for = ' and a number we can use a [Perl regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18892742/397817) (-P) and discard the first part of the match by using \K in our expression:

```
grep -Po 'value for \= \K[0-9]+' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "value for" YOURFILE | grep -Po '([\[0-9\]\.]+)'
```

The first grep makes sure only the necessary lines are passed to the second, which only outputs the matching parts (due to the `-o` switch).

Comment: No need for the initial cat. http://bencane.com/2013/08/19/grepping-a-file-without-using-cat-and-grep-other-tricks/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp that matches numbers. Something like:

```
\d?\.?\d*
```

Here is a screenshot of [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) in action:
[image]